# How to replace previous of path react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I am a little bit confused when I try to use `react-router-dom`. How can we replace the previous path when navigating to a new path. Because the code is too long I will simplify it.

For example we are in a component of `http://localhost:3000/register` and when user hit a button or change progmatically using `useNavigate()` to another component of `http://localhost:3000/login` . When I code and use `navigate` it will error since there is no matching route at `http://localhost:3000/register/login/`.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './Pages/Login';
import Register from './Pages/Register';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='login' element={<Login/>} />
      <Route path='register' element={<Register /> } />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My code in `register.js` after a click it should go to login page not add login to register path

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Register= () => {
  return (
    ///remove the backslash for login didnt change anything
    <Link style={{textDecoration:'none'}} to="/login">
      <Button
        sx={{marginTop:'10px',marginBottom:'10px'}} 
        variant="contained"
        color='primary'
      >
        <Typography>
          Login
        </Typography>
      </Button>
    </Link>
  )
}

export default Register
```

How to get rid of previous path in `react-router-dom`?

[first path or register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmuMp.jpg)

[got error since login path added to the register path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfmXU.jpg)

Comment: The console error is stating there is no matching route path for `"/login/profile"`. I don't see any overt issue with the code snippets you've shared, and in fact can't reproduce any routing/navigation issue with it in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-replace-previous-of-path-react-router-dom-qr8rnb). I think the issue is elsewhere in code you haven't shared with us. Please include all relevant code in a [mcve]. Feel free to also fork my sandbox and add more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue, and if so, please include a link to it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke after I read a lot of friends answer It actually a bug, there is a `useNavigate` in my code redirect to `profile` component rather being on click.

Answer (score 0):

component `Link` have property replace, which one will indicate that, need to replace `url` on `to` - but if you don't use `baseurl` in `<Routes>` )

Also you can see guide about `Link` - https://github.com/harryheman/React-Total/blob/main/md/react-router.md#link

Comment: Redirecting doesn't really have anything at all to do with the target path issue OP is describing. Additionally, it'd be better to link to the ***official docs*** and not some non-English fork. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/link